# How to integrate Microsoft Project Dashboard in web application?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, ms-project

I am working on a project where I need to integrate MS Project Dashboard in my angular based web application with Node backend api. We want to embed MS Project dashboard in our application. However, I don't know if this is possible and if possible from where should I begin.

I can find references to PowerBI Dashboard integrations but can't find anything about MS Project dashboard integration, even on microsoft.

I am wondering if anyone can provide me a direction or can share any references.
In the end what I want to achieve is user can create project on msproject from our web application.

Answer (score 0):

At this point the above functionality doesn't exists. But i remember [a related uservoice item](https://microsoftproject.uservoice.com/forums/914203-project-for-the-web/suggestions/40676659-allow-roadmaps-to-be-embedded-in-other-webpages) posted in the Microsoft uservoice/feature request. If you wish, go ahead, upvote it, so that it can be considered to be implemented.